# cron job using java not working but works fine when executed manually

Tags: java, linux, bash, jar, cron

My bash shell script is working perfectly when executed manually but it does not work on cron. I have declared the variables for java home but cron job is still not working. I have also used absolute paths in declaring jar files and config files. Here's a part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdkver
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

......

nohup "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java -Xms246m -Xmx2048m -jar /home/user/jars/jarfileneeded.jar /home/user/cfg/configurationneeded.properties &
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you tried to change your console user to the one used from crond? and then run that command manualy?

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by 'not working'. Do you have some log output we could look at to try and work out what is wrong.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @ReneM. it's in the same console as the one used from crond, also, it works fine when executed manually, but does not in cron

Comment: Hi @jr593 the app is starting because I grep the pid and it shows new process id number. but when i check on the logs of the application, it's not updating, meaning it does not get any data

Comment: Maybe the java program depends on certain environment variables being set?

Comment: Hi @123, the only variable it calls inside is java home which i declared right after #!/bin/bash. The application also only needs two things, the config.properties and jar file which I declared using absolute path.